# Storing lambda functions into dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

While exploring Python, I wanted to store lambda functions as values with boolean keys in the dictionary. So when I iterate through the dictionary if the key is True I call the respective function, but the problem is while I store the functions, one I use sqrt() method from the math library inside, will not be stored. I do not know the reason behind.
here is the code:

```
from math import sqrt
bool_list = [True, False, True]
func1 = lambda x: x ** 2
func2 = lambda x: x ** 3
func3 = lambda x: sqrt(x)
func_list = [func1, func2, func3]
dic = dict(zip(bool_list, func_list))
print(dic)
```

here is the output:
{True: <function  at 0x7f71e0464a60>, False: <function  at 0x7f71e0464d30>}

Comment: The keys of a dictionary must be unique, you have 2 `True` and 1 `False` so only one of the `True` key/value pairs will persist

Comment: For each key (like e. g. "True") only one value can be stored.

Comment: Store the *functions* as keys: `dic = dict(zip(func_list, bool_list))`. Then `for f in d: if d[f]: f()`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the type of the values